# Incorrect symbolic integration for Mathematica 11.1, limits do not match

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

hopefully someone can help me with this problem I am having. I am trying to calculate the integral

```
Integrate[(((a - 2) (2 x^2 - 1/2) + 2)) (((T x (x - 1)) + M)^(-a/2)), {x, 0, 1},  
GenerateConditions -> False]
```

Which should equal

```
Integrate[(((a - 2) (2 x^2 - 1/2) + 2)) (((T x (x - 1)))^(-a/2)), {x, 0, 1},
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

when I afterwards set M to zero. However, what I get is that the first integral equals

```
(2^(-3 + a) (10 - 3 a) Sqrt[\[Pi]] (-T)^(-a/2) Gamma[1 - a/2])/Gamma[5/2 -
 a/2]
```

Which is correct, yet in the limit M to 0, the first integral returns "ComplexInfinity". I have tried using variations of assumptions as well as no assumptions but I always encounter the same problem. I am relatively new to Mathematica, so I am not sure whether this is a bug or I am doing something wrong. Any help that people can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No matter what the sign of `T`, one of the last two arguments of `AppellF1` is infinite at `M == 0`.  Instead, try expanding the first solution about `M == 0`.

Comment: The two results are not  equal, as can be demonstrated by evaluating them at `{T -> 1, a -> 1, M -> 1/8}`.  However, there is no reason to suppose that they should be, because they may be valid only for different conditions on the parameters.

Comment: bbgodfrey, the solutions should be the same when M is specified to be zero surely, as then the two integrands become equal. If the two functions are being defined on different domains is there any way to specify the domains to be the same? I have tried adding the assumptions `T, M, a all real` as well as `M,a >=0`, but this does not change that the two integrals give different results.
Also expanding around M =0 is not ideal as i need to take the limit `a ->0` in the end, and that could introduce new problems

Comment: You can use `NIntegrate` in specific cases (i.e., for specific numerical values of the parameters) to verify which formulas are correct.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the comment and how to notify someone else of my responce, I know `NIntegrate` will probably solve this problem for specific values, the only problem is that I need the result to be a function of both T and M, and so I can`t put in specific values there. I understand it is possible to of course create a table with specific values but that will also not work for the application I need.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I was not suggesting you use `NIntegrate` in place of `Integrate`. The main weakness of my suggestion is that it can be used only as a spot-check to show a formula is wrong at a point value of `{T, M, a}`, but that would still be informative.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, I tried this but it did not really give me any information that I could decern. I think the problem is that I end up with a term `M^(-a/2)`, which then violates my global assumptions that `M>=0`, seeming instead to generate its own contradicting assumption that `Re[M]>0`, even when I specify that M is real. Is there any way to override this? I have tried using `{Elements[M,Reals],M>=0` in the integral but still get the same term of `M^(-a/2)`, which cannot be valid if M=0 right?

Comment: If you wish to see what I mean here is the code I am talking about
`trial2 = Refine[
  Integrate[((2 x^2 - 1/2) + 2) (((T x (x - 1)) + M)^(-a/2)), {x, 0, 
    1}], {Element[a, Reals], a < 2, Element[M, Reals], M >= 0}]`

Comment: Your last comment indicates that `M >= 0`.  Are their constraints on `T` and `a`?  For instance, are they real?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Hi sorry for the late reply have been busy so havent had any time to look more at this problem. Yes, T should be less than M, and a should be non-negative and less than 2. I have tried adding these constraints as well but it didnt change the solution.

Comment: The bottom line of my answer is that `Integrate` is unable to return an answer valid for `M >= 0`.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Your comment above states that `T < M`.  This would mean that `T` must be negative, so that the limit of `M -> 0` can be taken.  Is this your intent, or did you instead mean that `T > M`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey No T will in be negative for 'M=0', technically it is only required that T be strictly less than M for the solution I am trying to obtain, but it should be fine to have it be restricted to be negative for any M.

Answer (score 4):

In situations like this, it is prudent to obtain from `Integrate` the conditions under which a solution it provides is "guaranteed" valid.  This is accomplished by setting the option `GenerateConditions` to `True` instead of `False`.  Then

```
int = (((a - 2) (2 x^2 - 1/2) + 2)) (((T x (x - 1)) + M)^(-a/2));
Integrate[int, {x, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

produces a `ConditionalExpression` a bit long (`LeafCount` of 696) to reproduce here.  However,

```
FullSimplify[% /. M -> 0]
```

produces a less lengthy and more informative expression

```
(* ConditionalExpression[1/6 (0^(-a/2) 2^(2 + a) (-2 + a) 
   AppellF1[3, a/2, a/2, 4, (2 T)/(T - Sqrt[T^2]), (2 T)/(T + Sqrt[T^2])] + 
   (3 (-6 + a) T (Beta[(T - Sqrt[T^2])/(2 T), 1 - a/2, 1 - a/2] - 
                  Beta[(T + Sqrt[T^2])/(2 T), 1 - a/2, 1 - a/2]))/SqrtT^2]), 
   Re[T/Sqrt[T^2]] > 1 || Re[T/Sqrt[T^2]] < -1 || T/Sqrt[T^2] ∉ Reals] *)
```

Because this condition is not satisfied by any complex number, the result with `M == 0` is not valid, not does `Integrate` claim that it is.  So, the behavior described in the question is not a bug.  Rather, `Integrate` is unable to obtain a solution for general `M` that is also valid for `M == 0`.  This conclusion is corroborated by the fact that

```
Integrate[int, {x, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True, Assumptions -> M >= 0]
```

returns unevaluated.  Additional insight can be obtained by considering a specific case,

```
f[M0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[int /. {a -> 1, T -> 1, M -> M0}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20]
Plot[{Re@f[M], Im@f[M]}, {M, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-7, 10}]
```

[image]

Evidently, the integral is not differentiable with respect to `M` at `M == 0`, although it is continuous there.  `Integrate` gives the same curve with

```
Integrate{int /. {a -> 1, T -> 1}, {x, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True, 
    Assumptions -> M >= 0]
(* ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[M] + (7/2 + 2 M) ArcCoth[2 Sqrt[M]], M > 1/4] *)
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm @(% // First), {M, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-7, 10}]
```

even for `M < 1/4`.  (Whether an  overly restrictive condition constitutes a bug is, perhaps, a matter of opinion.)  On the other had, omitting the `Assumption` yields

```
Integrate[int /. {a -> 1, T -> 1}, {x, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/4 (-4 Sqrt[M] + (7 + 4 M) Log[-1 - 2 Sqrt[M]] - 
   (7 + 4 M) Log[1 - 2 Sqrt[M]]), Im[Sqrt[1 - 4 M]] != 0 || Re[Sqrt[1 - 4 M]] > 1] *)
```

For real `M`, `Integrate` asserts that the answer is valid when `M < 0`, and indeed this is true.

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm @(%13 // First), {M, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-7, 10}]
```

[image]

**Results with Assumptions on Constants**

The OP recently provided constraints on the three constants appearing in the integrand, `M >= 0`, `T < 0`, and `0 <= a < 2`.  Additionally, it is convenient to represent `M` as `m T`, with `m <= 0`.  Then, the integrand becomes

```
int = T^(-a/2) ((a - 2) (2 x^2 - 1/2) + 2) (x (x - 1) + m)^(-a/2)
```

with `T` now entering only through a multiplicative factor.  Applying the constraints then yields

```
Integrate[int, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 <= a < 2 && m < 0, GenerateConditions -> True];
sn = FullSimplify[%, 0 <= a < 2 && m < 0]
(* 1/6 T^(-a/2) (4 (-2 + a) E^(-(1/2) I a π) (-(1/m))^(a/2)
   AppellF1[3, a/2, a/2, 4, 2/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 m]), -(2/(-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 m]))] - 
   3 I (-6 + a) m^(1 - a/2) (-((I m)/Sqrt[1 - 4 m]))^(1/2 (-2 + a)) (-1 + 4 m)^(-a/4)
   (Beta[1/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[1 - 4 m]), 1 - a/2, 1 - a/2] - 
   Beta[1/2 (1 + 1/Sqrt[1 - 4 m]), 1 - a/2, 1 - a/2])) *)
```

Results can be obtained for positive `m` as well, although the results are a bit long to be reproduced here.

```
s4 = Integrate[int, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 <= a < 2 && 0 < m < 1/4, GenerateConditions -> True];
sp = Integrate[int, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 <= a < 2 && m > 1/4, GenerateConditions -> True];
```

Note that `Integrate` returned no additional constraints for any of these three results.  Consequently, the solution for all real `m` is

```
s = Piecewise[{{sn, m < 0}, {sp, m > 1/4}}, s4]
```

with, as a sample result,

```
Plot[s /. {a -> 1, T -> -1}], {m, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-10, Automatic}]
```

[image]

The corresponding numerical integration yields an identical plot.

```
f[m0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[int /. {a -> 1, T -> -1, m -> m0}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20]
Plot[{Re@f[m], Im@f[m]}, {m, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-10, Automatic}]
```

`s` can, of course, be plotted for other values of `a`, although the evaluation of `s` is quite slow for some `a` with `0 < m < 1/4`.  Since the question requested only `m < 0`, the slow speed for `0 < m < 1/4` does not really matter.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is really detailed which is great! The only thing that confuses me is that there does exist a solution when 'M=0', so does this mean that Integrate is returning a solution just valid on a subdomain of the whole M-domain of the solution?
That is to say the process that Integrate uses does not seem to be very general, but is there any way to make Integrate return an answer which is also valid when M=0? the restriction 'M>=0' does not seem to change the output of integrate.

Comment: @Ragemeistro  Precisely so.  `Integrate` seems unable to obtain a solution valid for all real `M`. The option  `GenerateConditions -> True` instructs `Integrate` to provide the range of parameters for which it knows its solution to be correct.  However, I have found a more general solution including `M` in the vicinity of zero, but I need an answer to my comment of a few minutes ago before proceeding.